# Android Layout Issue

Tags: android, layout, android-layout

Hi I'm having a daft problem with my android application.

Currently it looks like this:

[image]

Is there a way of making the button go to the bottom in the middle?  I've tried messing around but same effect.  Also tried changing the fill_parent/wrap_content, relative/linear layouts and gravities.

This is the screenshot of the .xml file

[image]

many thanks.

Comment: A screenshot of XML? _Really?_ Please just include the actual XML code into your question, [indented by 4 spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: I can't...Everytime I copy and paste xml code...it won't show it.

Comment: Read the link, amigo: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help. **Indent code blocks with 4 spaces.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these two attributes to your Button

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

and these one to your textview:

```
android:layout_above="@id/insertion"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

Read the API reference here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html

Comment: This TextView is handled automatically by the OS when there are no items in the list. If that did not work, you may need to create your own Activity instead of the prepackaged ListActivity and customize your display.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple things you can do to get this, with the relative layout you're using this would work. Add these lines to your button section

```
android:layout_below="@+id/android:empty"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentCenter="true"
```

Comment: If you're using it with a ListActivity, you would want the `android:empty` so that you can use the default `setEmptyView()` functions, and other related methods.

Comment: Hi for some reason this doesn't seem to affect the layout.  I'm still having the same issue :/

Comment: maybe add fillparent to the listview because it's empty and getting squished at the top

Answer (score 0):

May be you want to use a linear layout instead of the relative one...
With the LinearLayout you can place your item without thinking on their relative position.
You can place a vertical linear layout and inside it another layout for the list of reminders.

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView android:width="fill_parent"android:weight="2" />
<Button android:width="wrap_content" android:weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

With weight option, you can choose to make the Button to be painted before the ListView.

EDIT: Reading other answers, I'm considering if you really need a RelativeLayout to place a button under a listview. I think you should learn how to handle simple view before to start using something more complex. If LinearLayout solve your problem, why don't use it? This is a personal observation...